# How to get item Ids rather than item name when i select multiple items from a multi select spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

i'm developing an app which requires android multi select spinner items. i'm sable to get the spinner properly and select multiple items and separated by coma also but my problem is When i select a item i need to get the item value and i need to display item name at the spinner but send value as the item values :
 Example i have list of animals like : Lion,King,Elephant..etc these values like LN,KN,ELP..etc.. when i select Lion,King... i am  successfully able to show the coma(,) separated names on spinner but i need to send values as the LN,KN..

Here is my multi select spinner code :

```
public class MultiSelectionSpinner extends Spinner implements
        OnMultiChoiceClickListener {

    public interface OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener{
        void selectedIndices(List<Integer> indices);
        void selectedStrings(List<String> strings);
    }
    private OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener listener;

    String[] _items = null;
    boolean[] mSelection = null;
    boolean[] mSelectionAtStart = null;
    String _itemsAtStart = null;

    ArrayAdapter<String> simple_adapter;

    public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);

        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
    }

    public MultiSelectionSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        simple_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        super.setAdapter(simple_adapter);
    }

    public void setListener(OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
        if (mSelection != null && which < mSelection.length) {
            mSelection[which] = isChecked;
            simple_adapter.clear();
            simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Argument 'which' is out of bounds.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Please select!!!");
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(_items, mSelection, this);
        _itemsAtStart = getSelectedItemsAsString();
        builder.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                System.arraycopy(mSelection, 0, mSelectionAtStart, 0, mSelection.length);
                listener.selectedIndices(getSelectedIndices());
                listener.selectedStrings(getSelectedStrings());
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                simple_adapter.clear();
                simple_adapter.add(_itemsAtStart);
                System.arraycopy(mSelectionAtStart, 0, mSelection, 0, mSelectionAtStart.length);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(SpinnerAdapter adapter) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
                "setAdapter is not supported by MultiSelectSpinner.");
    }

    public void setItems(String[] items) {
        _items = items;
        mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];
        mSelectionAtStart = new boolean[_items.length];
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);
        Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
        mSelection[0] = true;
        mSelectionAtStart[0] = true;
    }

    public void setItems(List<String> items) {
        _items = items.toArray(new String[items.size()]);
        mSelection = new boolean[_items.length];
        mSelectionAtStart  = new boolean[_items.length];
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(_items[0]);
        Arrays.fill(mSelection, false);
        mSelection[0] = true;
    }

    public void setSelection(String[] selection) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
                mSelection[i] = false;
                mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
        }
        for (String cell : selection) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {
                if (_items[j].equals(cell)) {
                    mSelection[j] = true;
                    mSelectionAtStart[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public void setSelection(List<String> selection) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
            mSelection[i] = false;
            mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
        }
        for (String sel : selection) {
            for (int j = 0; j < _items.length; ++j) {
                if (_items[j].equals(sel)) {
                    mSelection[j] = true;
                    mSelectionAtStart[j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public void setSelection(int index) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
            mSelection[i] = false;
            mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
        }
        if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {
            mSelection[index] = true;
            mSelectionAtStart[index] = true;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                    + " is out of bounds.");
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public void setSelection(int[] selectedIndices) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mSelection.length; i++) {
            mSelection[i] = false;
            mSelectionAtStart[i] = false;
        }
        for (int index : selectedIndices) {
            if (index >= 0 && index < mSelection.length) {
                mSelection[index] = true;
                mSelectionAtStart[index] = true;
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index " + index
                        + " is out of bounds.");
            }
        }
        simple_adapter.clear();
        simple_adapter.add(buildSelectedItemString());
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedStrings() {
        List<String> selection = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                selection.add(_items[i]);
            }
        }
        return selection;
    }

    public List<Integer> getSelectedIndices() {
        List<Integer> selection = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                selection.add(i);
            }
        }
        return selection;
    }

    private String buildSelectedItemString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean foundOne = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                if (foundOne) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                foundOne = true;

                sb.append(_items[i]);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getSelectedItemsAsString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        boolean foundOne = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; ++i) {
            if (mSelection[i]) {
                if (foundOne) {
                    sb.append(", ");
                }
                foundOne = true;
                sb.append(_items[i]);
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Please update my code with how can i get  item values when i select item names. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Add library project from this link https://github.com/GunaseelanArumaikkannu/MultiSpinner/tree/master/libmultispinner

compile your library project inside app gradle `compile project(':libmultispinner')`

Your activity implement this listener `MultiSelectionSpinner.OnMultipleItemsSelectedListener`

```
String[] array = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"};
MultiSelectionSpinner multiSelectionSpinner = (MultiSelectionSpinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);


multiSelectionSpinner.setListener(this);

@Override
    public void selectedIndices(List<Integer> indices) {
}

@Override
public void selectedStrings(List<String> strings) {
    Toast.makeText(this, strings.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: That's all i already did .. that's y i can get the selected items with (,) separated and i want to know how to get the item Id for particular selected item

Comment: You can get Lion,King,etc, covert them to LN,KN is just another work.

Comment: yeah  but Lion,King as i take example scenario but my actual spinner array having different names string(ex:Guest,Offstring) with Integer Id(1000,2000..etc) . here i am getting Guest,Offspring .. etc values.. when i select those both i need to send their respective Ids like ... 1000,2000

Comment: id's are maintain list or what typed?

Comment: {
 "GuestDropdown": [{
   "GuestID": "XXX-XXXX-0002",
   "GuestName": "Perr"
  },
  {
   "GuestID": "XXX-XXXX-1344",
   "GuestName": "John"
  },
  {
   "GuestID": "XXX-XXXX-1234",
   "GuestName": "Doe"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: this list data i used for spinner adapter. when i select those guestnames i need to send those guestids to my server

Comment: where to assign guestnames value's that code can be update your question